# Android: Parsing special characters (ä,ö,ü) in JSON

Tags: android, json

How can I parse special characters in JSON? And since I'm making a German App, it includes a lots of special characters like ä,ö,ü,ß. How can I show those characters through parsing JSON? Right now they are only shown as '?'

Here's my JSON parsing method:

```
void examineJSONFile()
    {
        try
        {
            String y = "";
            InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.json);
            Writer writer = new StringWriter();
            char[] buffer = new char[1024];

            try {
              BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8")
              );
              int n;
              while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
              }
            } finally {
              is.close();
            }

            String jsontext = writer.toString();

            JSONArray entries = new JSONArray(jsontext);
            
            int j;
            for (j=0;j<entries.length();j++)
            {
                JSONObject post = entries.getJSONObject(j);
                y += post.getString("description") + "\n";
            }
            txt_beschreibung.setText(y);
        }
        catch (Exception je)
        {
            txt_beschreibung.setText("Error w/file: " + je.getMessage());
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that your JSON is encoded in UTF-8? If not you'll need to change the argument of the `InputStreamReader` constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such chars must be in UTF-8 encoding at least. Check if your file is saved in this incoding.

Comment: thanks for reminding, it appears that I saved the file in ANSI encoding. So I have changed it into UTF-8, the special chars are now shown but I get this error http://img687.imageshack.us/img687/497/scrshtq.jpg maybe you can help me. Thx

Comment: Similar issue here... Still no answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633212/cannot-parse-json-with-jsonarray-in-android

Answer (score 3):

first check encoding type in xml, either UTF-8 or ISO-8859-1

if encoding type is ISO-8859-1, then in programme just change this code for read special character

```
SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();

XMLReader xmlReader =  parser.getXMLReader();
xmlReader.setContentHandler(this);
InputSource is = new InputSource(xmlUrl.openStream());
is.setEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
xmlReader.parse(is);
```