# How to handle special characters in json string

Tags: android, json, character-encoding

I have an app where I store user entered text into a json string. I then store that json string into a file. And then later on display it back by reading the file, extracting the json string from it and finally getting the string to display into a textview. I am however noticing that any special characters(rather symbols) like £, ÷, € etc are not displayed back. For example the symbol € gets displayed as â□¬.

Some sample code below for reference

First the code for capturing user entered text and putting it into a file

```
//get user entered text
QuestionEditText = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.editTextQuestion);
//put that into json object
JSONObject jObjOneQuestionDetails=new JSONObject();
jObjOneQuestionDetails.put("Question", QuestionEditText.getText());
//write json object  into file
FileOutputStream output = openFileOutput("MyFileName",MODE_PRIVATE);
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(output);
writer.writejObjOneQuestionDetails.put());
writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

Now below the code for getting the string back from file and displaying it to user

```
//define and initialize variables
QuestionEditText = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.editTextQuestion);
private JSONArray jArrayQuizQuestions=new JSONArray();
private JSONObject jObjQuizTitle=new JSONObject();

//load JSONObject with the File
int ch;
StringBuffer fileContent = new StringBuffer("");
FileInputStream fis;
String fileString;
fis = this.getBaseContext().openFileInput("MyFileName");
while( (ch = fis.read()) != -1)
          fileContent.append((char)ch);
fileString = new String(fileContent);
jObjQuizTitle = new JSONObject(fileString);
jArrayQuizQuestions = jObjQuizTitle.getJSONArray("MyFileName");


//display json object into textview
JSONObject aQues = jArrayQuizQuestions.getJSONObject(pageNumber-1);
String quesValue = aQues.getString("Question");
QuestionEditText.setText(quesValue.toCharArray(), 0, quesValue.length());
```

The code above is just a sample, I have ignored any try/catch blocks here. This should give an idea about how I am capturing and displaying the user entered text.

Comment: Maybe it´s a problem with your char encoding. What does your code look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use **"UTF-8"** for using this kind of special character. For details read http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/charset/Charset.html

You have to encode for your expected character like this way :

```
URLEncoder.encode("Your Special Character", "UTF8");
```

You can check similar question about this issue from here :

[Android: Parsing special characters (ä,ö,ü) in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536140/android-parsing-special-characters-a-o-u-in-json)