# Special characters in object making JSON invalid (DataContractJsonSerializer)

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone, character

I'm trying to serialize an object which has a special character in on of his strings (like ø or æ).

The problem is that when I use a special character like that, the last bit of my JSON is cut off?

Without special characters:

```
{"availability":"busy","name":"test","visibility":"public"}
```

With special characters:

```
{"availability":"busy","name":"tøst","visibility":"public"
```

I notice that for each special character, a character is cut off of my JSON string.

I use following code to serialize:

```
// create new appointment
AppointmentClass appoint = new AppointmentClass();
appoint.name = subjectstring;
appoint.availability = "busy";
appoint.visibility = "public";

// generate json string from Appointment class
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(AppointmentClass));
ser.WriteObject(stream, appoint);
stream.Position = 0;
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
string payload = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19474547/how-to-handle-special-characters-in-json-string

Answer (score 4):

You need to use UTF-8 encoding. It will be something like this

```
DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(AppointmentClass));
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    serializer.WriteObject(ms, appoint);
//use utf encoding to accept special chars
    var mytext = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
```

More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/744y86tc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)