# Display special characters from json to textview android

Tags: android, json, textview

I have a json file on my assets folder, it contains texts such as ñ , i displayed it on textview the problem is,it didn't display as ñ. Heres my code for accessing my json file :

```
 public String loadJSONFile() {
        String json = null;
        try {

            InputStream is = getAssets().open("map.json");

            int size = is.available();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

            is.read(buffer);

            is.close();   

            json = new String(buffer,"UTF-8");


        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return json;

    }
```

Comment: It's better to fully explain what you have, what you get and what you want. With a question like this, guys here can't help you efficiently :)

Comment: Check the encoding. JSON is supposed to be UTF-8, and your textfile might not be.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use "UTF-8" encoding for using this kind of special character.

Reference : [How to handle special characters in json string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19474547/how-to-handle-special-characters-in-json-string)