# Special charcter display issue

Tags: android

My android application uses a web service.The web service returns response in json format (which is UTF8 encoded). Here I am using the same for decoding the json data. still some special symbols(eg degree celcius symbol) are displays a question mark

```
InputStream is = con.getInputStream(); 
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"));
```

JSON:

```
{
    "option1":"109.5?",
    "option2":"109?",
    "option3":"120?",
    "option4":"180?",
    "ans_o‌​ption":"",
    "qd_id":76,
    "questions":"In alkanes the bond angle is"
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code and the json ?

Comment: InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"));  JSN:"option1":"109.5?","option2":"109?","option3":"120?","option4":"180?","ans_option":"","qd_id":76,"questions":"In alkanes the bond angle is"}

Answer (score 0):

You have to use "UTF-8" Mark for this issue:
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/charset/Charset.html

## You have to encode for your expected character like this way :

> `URLEncoder.encode("Your Special Character", "UTF8");`

### Check this question as well:

> [Android: Parsing special characters (ä,ö,ü) in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536140/android-parsing-special-characters-a-o-u-in-json)

Comment: it is not encoding actually. the string is encoded from server side and herewe are decoding it